# Multiple nested arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am having difficulties figuring out an effective way of working with a multiple nested document. It looks like the following:

```
  { "_id" : 
      { "$oid" : "53ce46e3f0c25036e7b0ddd8"} , 
          "someid" : 7757099 , 
          "otherids" : 
                  [ {    "id" : 100 , 
                         "line" : "test" , 
                         "otherids" : 
                                [ { "id" : 129}]}
   ]}
```

and there will be another level of array in addition.

I can not find a way to query this structure except for "otherids" array, but no deeper. Is this possible to do in an effective way at all?

These arrays might grow a bit, but not hugely.

My thought was to use it like this since it will be effective to fetch a lot of data in one go. But this data also needs to be updated quite often. Is this a hopeless solution with mongoDB?

Regards mongoDB newb

EDIT:
I would like to do it as simply and fast as possible :-)

Like: someid.4.otherids.2.line -> somevalue

I know that probably I would have to do a query to check if values exist, but it would be nice to do it as an upsert. Now I only work with objects in java, and it takes 14 secs to insert 10 000 records. Most of these inserts are "leaf nodes", meaning I have to query, then find out what is already there,  modify the document, then update the whole root. This takes too long.

Comment: And if anyone has recommendations for reading about nested queries within java, that would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't show how you'd like to query or update these docs, but in general, docs with deeply nested arrays can be difficult to work with in MongoDB.  I'd avoid their use if possible.